# Guessing Game in C programming

Tags: c

I built a guessing game in C programming using while loop, and I am having a problem with it during execution. So, when I print a number less than the guess number or greater than the guess number, I get the correct answer. But when the user enters the right answer, the screen shows the statement for the greater number "The number you entered is greater than the Secret Number." and then it shows the right statement below this "This is the secret Number." I think the problem could be because else statement does not define the condition for greater number but I am not sure how to solve this. Can somebody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        //Guessing game
        const int SecretNum = 4;
        int guess;
        while (guess != SecretNum){
                printf("Enter a number: ");
                scanf("%d", &guess);
                if (guess < SecretNum){
            printf("The number you entered is less than the Secret Number. \n");
                } else printf("The number you entered is greater than the Secret Number.\n");
                }
          printf("This is the secret number.\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You think the problem could be because else statement does not define the condition for greater number, so try adding that.

Comment: Also don't forget to initialize `guess` before using its value.

Answer (score 1):

You think the problem could be because else statement does not define the condition for greater number, so you should add that.

Also you have to initialize `guess` before using its value.

Formatting your code using indent properly is another important portion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Guessing game
    const int SecretNum = 4;
    int guess = !SecretNum; /* initialize guess : guess will be different value from SecretNum using this */
    while (guess != SecretNum){
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if (guess < SecretNum){
            printf("The number you entered is less than the Secret Number. \n");
        } else if (guess > SecretNum) /* add condition */
            printf("The number you entered is greater than the Secret Number.\n");
    }
    printf("This is the secret number.\n");
    return 0;
}
```